# Sending an Email with Gmail Smtp, but it doesnt send?

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send an email through code using gmail smtp however, it just wont send to the user. The sent emails are indeed in the "sent email" folder and in the correct format. I tried sending the email regularly to see if its perhaps the email address but everything sent fine. I am not sure why this isnt working... Any ideas would be appreciated.

The code:

```
//this will build the email and send it 
        public void sendEmail()
        {
          var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GlobalVars.strFromEmail, "pass"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send(GlobalVars.strFromEmail,GlobalVars.strEmailAddress, "test", "testbody");
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

FIXED: Nevermind everyone, it was just taking an extremly long time to send (like an hour)...

Comment: Maybe your sender address is not your own gmail address and google prevents sending mails from different senders to avoid spam?

Comment: Try creating a second gmail email address, send the email to the new account.  If the email is received in the new account, then a few things could cause this.  The first would be a lag in between the two email providers.  The second could be the email address you are trying to send to.  The third could be that the intended email service provider has Gmail blocked (This is not uncommon as firewalls will automatically block providers in the event that spam flooding occurs).

Comment: Antivirus programs like McAfee are known to block email.  This is typically port 25, but I've had to disable McAfee Enterprise onaccess scanner to get this to work, before.

Answer (score 0):

You better use try catch block to see what kind of error message is listed.

Comment: Try catch is good for issues that prevent the code from running, but his issue is that Gmail is not forwarding the emails like it should.